# opamp simulation

Tags: operational-amplifier, simulation, ltspice, transient, loop-gain

Is the following open loop transient simulation of [opamp](https://gist.github.com/promach/e9fabef7dbe400984733fb48ec988c0d#file-opamp-asc) correct ?

[image: opamp circuit]

Comment: You just show a failed result with no verification of bias levels . Did you expect it to bias in saturation zone for high gain?  Looks like a theoretical diagram with low margins for stable operating point to me

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 The culprit is M11. Vgd of M11 is 1.2V-0.25V ~= 1V. How to make M11 to be in saturation region ?

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I have updated my [opamp circuit](https://i.imgur.com/Qen7FBF.png) with negative feedback and the output voltage is now less than 2.5V

And all mosfets are in saturation.

[Please correct me if wrong](https://gist.github.com/promach/e9fabef7dbe400984733fb48ec988c0d#file-opamp-asc)

Comment: I remember trying to bias this double complementary cascade by tweaking the bias and gm and got lots of gain but tons of quadratic gain ... harmonic distortion it was too sensitive, so bad, I found it unusable. even after negative FB

Comment: it came from some research paper that did not discuss tolerances  ( typical of some academic articles)  Did you use Vt=0.7? or .5? (I forget) the gate threshold is very critical and also gm

Comment: I think it was supposed to be a Gilbert cell

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 , it is definitely NOT gilbert cell

Comment: I agree but I don't think it does anything useful from the hours I spent trimming the design.  What Vt and gm did you use?  Check all your bias voltages at every node yet ?  .. not just the output which is Vdd/2

Comment: I just checked all mosfets are in saturation or not. I use Vth=0.7V

By the way, the circuit has so little [gain-bandwidth product](https://i.imgur.com/N84pwPy.png). Why ?

Comment: hard to tell with so little measurements... but this works ... sort of  http://tinyurl.com/y3yysvqn

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 See this updated [schematics](https://i.imgur.com/yq0jFYo.png)

Comment: I see the inputs but not the Node outputs.  I'm sure you can find the same problems that I once found here by examining each transistor state.  Falstad's is better for interactive tuning. It's a delicate balance.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the [phase margin of this circuit](https://i.imgur.com/ACT47af.png) ?

Comment: 80 deg PM is good but I wonder how bad nonlinearity is. I expect it to be poor without neg FB. and DC bias tolerances in the middle are unstable.

Comment: Huh ? How do you obtain 80 degree PM from my phase plot ?

I thought the screenshot I posted just now said 16.28 degree

Comment: I see a non-inverting response rise from 0 to 16, I had estimated this loss to be about 80 deg margin but actually 74 deg but that seems to be incorrect

Comment: but that seems to be incorrect because 100pF and high Zout in saturation ought to be very low f cutoff and 90 deg phase shift not shown.

Comment: but perhaps your Zout is much lower like 10 Ohms ??